# $2$-cocycles with values in non-abelian group

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group which acts trivially on an abelian group $A$. The abelian group $Z^{2}(G,A)$ denotes the set of
all $2$-cocycles $c$ on $G$ with values in $A$.
Now, let $c\in Z^{2}(G,A)$ and $\alpha\in \mathrm{Hom}(A,G)$. By applying $\alpha$ to the $2$-cocycle condition of $c$, we see that $\alpha\circ c$ satisfies the $2$-cocycle condition. But I'm not sure how we can say that $\alpha\circ c\in Z^{2}(G,G)$. That is, since $G$ is non-abelian, how are $Z^{2}(G,G)$ and $B^{2}(G,G)$ defined?. In which conditions on $G$ such that $\alpha\circ c=1$ for all $c\in Z^{2}(G,A)$ and $\alpha\in \mathrm{Hom}(A,G)$?.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: See [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368093/non-abelian-ext-functor-and-non-abelian-h2) for non-abelian $H^2$. You can also use  [factor systems](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_16_coho_course.pdf), see the work of Zassenhaus (or the group theory book by Suzuki).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you.